# Swift concurrency multiple await for single async result

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

I have `AuthorizationRequester` which can be call from many places simultaneously, but only first call can run `requestAuthorizationFromUser()` (and wait dozen of seconds for user interaction) - rest of these calls should `await` for result from `requestAuthorizationFromUser()`, but can't call it directly.

Look at the code:

```
actor AuthorizationRequester {
    enum SimpleResult {
        case success, failure
    }
    
    typealias ResultCompletion = (SimpleResult) -> ()
    
    private var requestInProgress = false
    private var requestCompletions = [ResultCompletion]()
    
    func request(completion: @escaping ResultCompletion) async {
        requestCompletions.append(completion)
        
        guard !requestInProgress else { return }
        
        requestInProgress = true
        
        let result = await requestAuthorizationFromUser()
        
        requestCompletions.forEach { $0(result) }
        requestCompletions.removeAll()
        requestInProgress = false
    }
    
    private func requestAuthorizationFromUser() async -> SimpleResult {
        // ...some code
    }
}
```

Everything works, but I really don't like `async` combined with `completion` closure :)

Is there any possibility to rewrite this function to version with header `func request() async -> SimpleResult` and same functionality?

Comment: Why do you need the completions at all? Just get rid of the array and change the signature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save multiple calls to an `async` method `await` the same `Task` associated with the authorization request:

```swift
actor AuthorizationRequester {
    private var task: Task<SimpleResult, Never>?

    func request() async -> SimpleResult {
        if task == nil {
            task = Task { await requestAuthorizationFromUser() }
        }

        return await task!.value
    }

    private func requestAuthorizationFromUser() async -> SimpleResult {…}
}
```

We do not have to maintain the closures ourselves, but rather just just deal with `Task` objects and let Swift concurrency handle it from there.

And if you want to reset it again when the `Task` finishes (like your sample effectively does), you can set it to `nil` when done:

```swift
actor AuthorizationRequester {
    private var previousTask: Task<SimpleResult, Never>?

    func request() async -> SimpleResult {
        let task: Task<SimpleResult, Never>

        if let previousTask {
            task = previousTask
        } else {
            task = Task { await requestAuthorizationFromUser() }
            previousTask = task
        }

        return await withTaskCancellationHandler {
            defer { previousTask = nil }
            return await task.value
        } onCancel: {
            task.cancel()
        }
    }

    …
}
```

Note, because this is [unstructured concurrency](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency#Unstructured-Concurrency) (where we bear the burden for handling cancelation), we should wrap this in [`withTaskCancellationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withtaskcancellationhandler(operation:oncancel:)). I presume you are likely not contemplating the cancelation of this authorization at this point, but as a practical matter, whenever writing unstructured concurrency, we should make sure we support cancelation.